# Mininet dump information is not updated after an ifconfig command

Tags: python, dump, mininet, ifconfig

We are using Mininet for teaching purposes, as a network emulator where our students can define their own IP networks and routing tables. There is a common issue when we update the IP address of a network interface. For example, using the default topology of Mininet (two hosts and 1 switch, and both hosts belonging to 10.0.0.0/8) if we change their IP addresses by means of `ifconfig`:

```
h1 ifconfig h1-eth0 192.168.1.1/24
h2 ifconfig h2-eth0 192.168.1.2/24
```

And we then type `dump` we obtain the following information:

```
<Host h1: h1-eth0:10.0.0.1 pid=1169>
<Host h2: h2-eth0:10.0.0.2 pid=1173>
```

and the `pingall` command does not work.

Is there any way to force that the information is updated by means of a python method or similar? We have checked that if we send a packet to the host the information is updated, but that is impractical and tedious for topologies composed by dozens of hosts.

I know that `py h1.setIP()` would solve the problem, but it is important for our purposes to keep using the OS commands like `ifconfig` instead of making use of python calls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In mininet, a switch is by default created as a Layer-2 switch, and it by default has several rules. You can use

```
sh ovs-ofctl dump-flows s1
```

to check the flow rules in s1.

So before you change the IP addresses of h1 and h2, the rules look like:

```
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4)
```

which is empty.

Then you enter pingall, the switch will add rules according to the original IP addresses(10.0.0.1 & 10.0.0.2), which may look like:

```
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=1.376s, table=0, n_packets=2, n_bytes=196, idle_timeout=60, idle_age=1, priority=65535,icmp,in_port=2,vlan_tci=0x0000,dl_src=f6:6b:f6:42:44:ac,dl_dst=06:37:92:eb:2c:a0,nw_src=10.0.0.2,nw_dst=10.0.0.1,nw_tos=0,icmp_type=0,icmp_code=0 actions=output:1
 cookie=0x0, duration=1.375s, table=0, n_packets=1, n_bytes=98, idle_timeout=60, idle_age=1, priority=65535,icmp,in_port=2,vlan_tci=0x0000,dl_src=f6:6b:f6:42:44:ac,dl_dst=06:37:92:eb:2c:a0,nw_src=10.0.0.2,nw_dst=10.0.0.1,nw_tos=0,icmp_type=8,icmp_code=0 actions=output:1
 cookie=0x0, duration=1.374s, table=0, n_packets=1, n_bytes=98, idle_timeout=60, idle_age=1, priority=65535,icmp,in_port=1,vlan_tci=0x0000,dl_src=06:37:92:eb:2c:a0,dl_dst=f6:6b:f6:42:44:ac,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=10.0.0.2,nw_tos=0,icmp_type=0,icmp_code=0 actions=output:2
```

And mininet will map "h1" to 10.0.0.1 and "h2" to 10.0.0.2

Now If you change IP to 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.1.2/24. The rules remains for 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2. Then after the 60 seconds idle timeout, it becomes empty again.

So if you want to connect to each other using your new IPs. You can try to use single ping with the host name such as:

```
h1 ping h2
h2 ping h2
```

to change the mapping in Mininet, then you can ping each other again.